# Linux Kernel Hardware Timer as Counter

Tags: c, linux, timer, kernel, hardware

I am using a timer (timer4) on the sunxi A20 platform as a counter connected to the external clock in for tmr4, to count external events. I am writing a small driver so I can read it from userspace.
My question is: is there a "proper" way or API to access hardware timers this way? For the moment I just access the raw register, which works, but I am wondering if there is another more clean way to do this.

Comment: You are very likely not the first. Why not check other projects? RasPi, BeagleBoard, CubbieBoard, etc.?

Comment: I did some research but it seems people are mostly interested in hw timers for hr timers or using them for periodic events. Moreover in the kernel version I have to use (3.4.90) there is not even the pinctrl driver for sunxi, and I could not find references to general purpose timers.

Comment: So any answer would be primarily opinion based, or depend on your application and personal experience resp. capabilities.